# yum : using boost 1.69 instead of default (1.53) version on centos

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, centos, yum

I want to compile (c++/cmake) code using boost 1.69. I am on centos 7.

After :

```
sudo yum install boost-devel.x86.64
```

the code compiles fine, but using the default version which is 1.53.

If I look at the libraries installed in /lib64, I see for example:

```
>> ls -al  /lib64/ | grep boost_timer
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root          27 Jun  9 11:50 libboost_timer-mt.so -> libboost_timer-mt.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root       19848 Apr  1 04:26 libboost_timer-mt.so.1.53.0
```

The yum installation for boost 1.69 is also available. So I can do:

```
sudo yum install boost169-devel.x86_64
```

which updates for example the content of /lib64/

```
>> ls -al  /lib64/ | grep boost_timer
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root          27 Jun  9 11:50 libboost_timer-mt.so -> libboost_timer-mt.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root       19848 Apr  1 04:26 libboost_timer-mt.so.1.53.0
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root          24 Jun  9 11:50 libboost_timer.so -> libboost_timer.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root       19848 Apr  1 04:26 libboost_timer.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root       24104 Apr 23  2019 libboost_timer.so.1.69.0
```

also :

```
>> ls /usr/include/ | grep boost
boost
boost169
```

At this point my workspace still compiles, but still using 1.53.

I would like my workspace to compile using 1.69. I could achieve this by botching 
FindBoost.cmake but this does not feel like the clean thing to do.

Also I tried (yum) removed boost-dev.x86-64, which removed the folder /usr/include/boost and the related so files in /lib64, which leaves for example:

```
>> ls -al /lib64/ | grep boost_timer
libboost_timer-mt.so.1.53.0
libboost_timer.so.1.53.0
libboost_timer.so.1.69.0
```

(note that there is no longer a "libboost_timer-mt.so")

At this point I believe I could also get my workspace to compile by manually creating symbolic links /usr/include/boost and /lib64/libboost_*.so , but that does also not feel like the clean thing to do

(note: I created the symbolic link /usr/include/boost pointing to /usr/include/boost64/boost, and indeed cmake stopped complaining about BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR, but because I did not create the symbolic links for the libraries, cmake still complains about those).

Is there a cleaner alternative way to manual creation of symbolic links ?

---

edit : I did create manually symbolic links for all the boost related libraries the compiler was complaining about, and I can confirm this worked.

Comment: Why don't you just source install 1.73 from boost.org?

Comment: @user14717 because using system-provided libraries is the way to go on an enterprise OS which CentOS is. Compiling with source installed library is not secure thing to do, even if it is newer. The system provided library will have security backports via package updates, source install will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there's obviously `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR` which you can use to control where boost headers, so why not just

```
cmake -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/include/boost169 \
  -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib64/boost169 \
  ...
```

Comment: yop, that helps with the include. What about the linkage ?

Comment: @Vince I believe you're after `-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib64/boost169`

Comment: I was more hoping about a way to set boost 1.69 has the "default" boost, i.e. no need to set compilation option. It may be not feasible, in which case I'll set your answer as the valid one.

Comment: I would agree that it is not feasible. But setting OS-specific compile options isn't a big issue: if you're going to build an RPM for the app, that would be just a few lines of code in the `.spec` file with a conditional. The resulting RPM file will depend on, e.g. `libboost_timer.so.1.69.0` (automatically added by `rpmbuild`). With this dependency, when users `yum install` the RPM, it will resolve to the right package `boost169-timer` (from EPEL).

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to setting the default for CMake is to set `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` as environment variables. `FindBoost.cmake` explicitly looks for those variables in the environment (something CMake does not do by default). So you can globally `export BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/include/boost169` and `export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib64/boost169` somewhere, or you can also wrap command invocations with, e.g., `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/include/boost169 BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib64/boost169 ./mybuild.sh` (assuming that `mybuild.sh` ends up invoking CMake or handles those environment variables itself, of course).